# Prove if sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is cauchy, it is componentwise cauchy

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Can I get a proof verification on this one?

Prove that $\{\textbf{u}_k\}$ is a cauchy sequence if and only if each component sequence is cauchy.

Attempt:

$(\Rightarrow)$. Since $\{\textbf{u}_k\}$ is cauchy for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $K \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k,l \geq K \implies \text{dist}(\textbf{u}_k,\textbf{u}_l)<\epsilon$.

Let $p_i(\textbf{u})$ be the $i$th coordinate of $\textbf{u}$. Then

for each $1 \leq i \leq n$, $k,l \geq K \implies 0 \leq |p_i(\textbf{u}_k-\textbf{u}_l)|\leq ||\textbf{u}_k-\textbf{u}_l||< \epsilon$ so it is componentwise cauchy.

$(\Leftarrow)$If $\{\textbf{u}_k\}$ is componentwise cauchy for $\epsilon>0$ for each $i$, there is a $K_i \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $k,l \geq K_i \implies |p_i(\textbf{u}_k-\textbf{u}_l)|<\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{n}}$

choose $K=\text{max}\{K_1,...K_n\}$ Then $k,l \geq K \implies$

$||\textbf{u}_k-\textbf{u}_l||=\sqrt{(p_1(\textbf{u}_k-\textbf{u}_l))^2+\dots+(p_n(\textbf{u}_k-\textbf{u}_l))^2}<\epsilon$

Comment: Looks good. To aid a lazy grader or reader I might add more detail as to the last inequality (i.e. substitute in the assumed information about p_i(u_k -u_j) into the sum and add it up and take the square root. But this is clear enough to me.

Comment: Looks good to me. Well done!